# Недопустимый термин ")" в выражении

Tags: c#

```
if (sim == + )
{
            Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
}
else if (sim == -)
{
            Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
}
```

Вот код, помогите пожалуйста, я новичок.

Comment: что это значит `sim == +`?

Comment: Если у вас sim, + и - это символы, то оберните их в одинарные ковычки: `sim == '+'`

Comment: походу вам надо почитать про разницу операторов и [литералов](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.26.php) в c#

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ

Answer (score 3):

Вы хотите проверить символьную переменную на значение, символы в C# заключаются в одинарные кавычки, следовательно если вы проверяете символьную переменную на значения + или -, то эти символы в коде должны быть обернуты в одинарные кавычки.

```
if (sim == '+')
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
}
else if (sim == '-')
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
}
```

Comment: Оно так и стоит с одним табом

Comment: @MaxXx обратите внимание на кавычки рядом с `==`.

Comment: Ошибка CS0019 Оператор "==" невозможно применить к операнду типа "int" и "string".

Comment: @MaxXx Как вы вводите в sim значение? С консоли?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден! Нужно было поставить одинарные скобки.

```
if (sim == '+')
        {
            (Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2));
        }
        else if (sim == '-')
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: это не ответ, покажите код, который является решением вашего вопроса

Comment: То, что вы заменили двойные кавычки на одинарные, не могло изменить тип переменной sim.

Comment: @Exodus `char` имеет неявную конвертацию в `int`.

Comment: @Exodus там шёл каст char к int

Comment: Второй WriteLine с табулированием

Comment: Не стоит создавать много учетных записей на StackOverflow. Используйте одну учутную запись. Вопрос и ответ даны с разных учетных записей.

Comment: Я тогда просил без учетной записи, а сейчас окончательно зарегистировался.

Comment: Какого типа изначально была переменная sim?

Comment: @Exodus очевидно же `char` :)

Comment: int вместе с num1 num2

Comment: System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат." а это уже что?

Comment: @Exodus dynamic :)

Comment: @MaxXx вот и проблема, вы не можете отредактировать свой же вопрос, потому что зашли с другой учетной записи. Разберитесь с учетками.